# Got DOWN touch before receiving UP or CANCEL from last gesture

Tags: android, react-native

I am creating react native bridge and custom EditText component in Android, but it is not touchable. I get this every time

**Got DOWN touch before receiving UP or CANCEL from last gesture**

I tried to google it, found some answers but none of them applies to my case. I don't use navigation package and I am using the latest ReactNative version.

What is interesting is that I can navigate to it by keyboard cursor down in emulator. In that case, I can input text.

You can see here explained strange behauvior.

[image]

Can somebody explain what is going on here?

I found source code for that view, but not sure how it works...
[ReactRootView](https://www.javatips.net/api/React-Native-Remote-Update-master/node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/ReactRootView.java)